# nwjs app javascript protection?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

So nwjs is a neat little framework that enables node apps to run in desktop mode independent to platform. But the way I package my files is pretty raw.

I zip my node app directory into a .nw file, and I copy it to an existing nwjs app's content folder. Then this means that anyone with some knowledge of nwjs will be able to literally unzip the .nw file and dig through the app directory. WTF. Is there a way to protect my files in my nwjs app?

Comment: @jfriend00 um no this has nothing to do with web development or any of your proposals, you can compile JavaScript to binary and as Mike0 described in his answer, the downside of 30% perfermance degrees has to be accounted for. It's like compiling anything to binary that can be decompiled and as a _hacker_ (whoever you mean using that terminology) you only get a certain percentage of the original code which in the end, is pretty useless.

Answer (score 9):

You can compile the javascript files with snapshot:

```
 nwjc source.js binary.bin
```

then load the compiled js in your app like this

```
 require('nw.gui').Window.get().evalNWBin(null, 'binary.bin');
```

for more info, check  [this](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Protect-JavaScript-source-code-with-v8-snapshot) out.

Comment: performance issues resolved per https://nwjs.io/blog/js-src-protect-perf/